# String formatting to remove \n in Python test

Tags: python, string-formatting

I've a json object in my python program that looks like this, the whole key is in a single line string with `\n` identifying new lines:

```
{
  "key": {
    "id":"2605c6c7-59e3-45cb-8483-a7a34ce6e008",
    "value":"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\nrWhfLZz9Uuu7E5zRv11MRbqVARwv4c1qQPAxJGwpAXLmQPpqwy4=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
   }
}
```

If I was to create it without the`\n`(see below) character I would get a formatting error.

```
{
  "key": {
    "id":"2605c6c7-59e3-45cb-8483-a7a34ce6e008",
    "value":"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
   }
}
```

I'm trying to write a test for this. I'll read the key from a file and it will already be in the format containing `\n`. How can I be sure it's been reformatted? If I print the top value to console it appears as the bottom.

Comment: Try ```"value": r"your_priv_key"``` see for instance: https://www.codevscolor.com/python-raw-string/

Comment: When you say `a json object`, do you mean a Python dictionary, or do you mean you load it from a json string?

Comment: Wait, first you say this is a JSON object in your Python program (i.e. in the source code), then you say you read it from a file. Which one is it? You need to provide a [mre].

Comment: We need a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Use triple quotes (`"""`) instead, it will resolve the problem. You see only **Python** take new line with triple quotes.

```py
{
  "key": {
    "id":"2605c6c7-59e3-45cb-8483-a7a34ce6e008",
    "value":"""-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAymUpP05OvlSykZBv9WDyexlREK7tzmAg56ivNmUJwT8ID0ig
a/Kiq9U5hDurfkQlD1gIJ7y8GA6IQnRxbha/LKm9TK878VIzAOtpdlVGeEa6SD5X
G2DPH8V+Q6cbhliN4NqvuiJqCDVR5W1CCQBNNotpbZirm9kX8NAlwOdtpoFGziX4
TgiNPcGbwaDDCpLiu4xfU6Uywv1e/EOvhZLqJpxuoKM7rdMaSM4/GIEBBQFlWPw+
NJtbnyqdPtw73xy8WFlSamzYrMazyrtlDiMPoWc0Un+dttwWix0awwtuLc4MAxBx
4wcxJLWctUCCNi+uf0qchhUwIsrSUA/9vC/6PQIDAQABAoIBABhzIgl4v0B04OF+
zleZL5G5XDakuyucJz10/j2W9Re4MpQOFPsVY5tYdctIng3x03xICSwru5k4YDOO
94jyDIQruSeDX71mTa0Fw0a9RHcRLD2/8ivnhP30kK1BiaywE+ue322f7KkzL8KE
cV6+/5TgQIsxz0FTd3Xq3zSvgGqFqnK+oWFl/vdM2KQW6qdpDcVr26gVwDyCbzNg
keFhs783Ek5nkscutx9BZyYwtRqcqwf/1h9VFVbIFa2dcQSvkE8hiIEkMh3tPTpM
TVs96OBSla9zEq5VcGIRCXYIgaD4AoR2RdsDC2ogFTeWWvwV4b8jBo7/KFKyfb+J
15m03CECgYEA6KHaZHhk7d4lyqsgHpmhJN/qR2vR9VflmUZf/5zfiSmz1s40g21T
l4g8sZxushSG9zDuZlG/BLgIgi9oaZ81FbhdWSU+zC9HPmepk6CU/MyzRqc8xEzz
iNDlj2dzO9hh+Q/MwAJv5TbPnE8V2vGWrLu30EDoEEH1UqVFrOfcjQkCgYEA3rnC
qj35PDDj1Gun+Hh0oTnGFItlrUppjuAox5zKXX+VBXTK94pWHIpsB8pkhykSnNPK
xoyEsEhR6j5VwtqUObqZ+gZDxRbrEOc9at/idyDF+Kl1SdS9r5lA55OJNDGbK80M
+RIh1yDHRZNJ1rCaPbadQIxCQveKHDwN9QLfxJUCgYAxPZEskw9KCiuVqoMx9vLV
C1BbrcbTV7eRqgPH5zypm9olLaCP8SQwfvXZ4nLL3uxyhjjwD32PUiT66W4AbWKf
Jlcb93ZDYf6Chw6t4N+oYuvPmLaUFnW2EAGHSS5rDHIwddexDNMCgYeQXm0R2vE5
vsI5ooN8bXmv9Ku63ZkhgQKBgHONKnqKdpEMyFa/l8CoNdIjmCm2fITgU02F7IJL
TQ4fD+BpzJeK1Mwv4IZWMbuRyo9ErjI+WuTeUGlX98SFBFvC/PmjYGuTTVdSsSGO
j/7AKRWuTSSF0/eTagH7IDbM+bVKx8085AOphNkK5kcVDqCv6nu/iO0XYjbtzUvt
NszVAoGALOD/MPI4G+THe5xn6DSYaRyt7LMafbxSsJCGgNkACfJy1Q37RZJv7c6K
skk8kaUfwWKQG7Qey4uedqfllf02DiSY7Y4BuGJraRZ5O4V53EyzpNkEk/6D8F2h
rWhfLZz9Uuu7E5zRv11MRbqVARwv4c1qQPAxJGwpAXLmQPpqwy4=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"""
   }
}
```

Comment: I fixed your terminology for you. A [docstring](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-docstring) is a specific usage of a string. [Triple quotes](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-triple-quoted-string) are recommended for docstrings, but they're not required.